# disabling _spark_metadata in Structured streaming in spark 2.3.0

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, parquet, spark-structured-streaming

My Structured Streaming application is writing  to parquet and i want to get rid of the _spark_metadata folder its creating. I used below property and it seems fine

`--conf "spark.hadoop.parquet.enable.summary-metadata=false"`

When the application starts no `_spark_metadata` folder is generated. But once it moves to RUNNING status and starts processing messages, it's failing with the below error saying `_spark_metadata` folder doesn't exist. Seems structured stream is relying on this folder without which we can't run. Just wondering if disabling metadata property makes any sense in this context. Is this a bug that the stream is not referring to the conf?

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File /_spark_metadata does not exist.
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Hdfs.listStatus(Hdfs.java:261)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util$1.next(FileContext.java:1765)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util$1.next(FileContext.java:1761)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FSLinkResolver.resolve(FSLinkResolver.java:90)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1761)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1726)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileContext$Util.listStatus(FileContext.java:1685)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog$FileContextManager.list(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:370)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.HDFSMetadataLog.getLatest(HDFSMetadataLog.scala:231)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink.addBatch(FileStreamSink.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$3$$anonfun$apply$16.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:477)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.MicroBatchExecution$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$MicroBatchExecution$$runBatch$3.apply(MicroBatchExecution.scala:475)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.ProgressReporter$class.reportTimeTaken(ProgressReporter.scala:271)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason this was happening is that the kafkacheckpoint folder was not cleanedup. the files inside the kafka checkpointing was cross referencing the spark metadata files and failing .once i removed both it started working

Comment: Is it advised to clean up kafka checkPoint folder as it will start reading from first message in kafka? Or you have found  a solution for this as well.